# running the collatz sequence code from automate the boring stuff with python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to programming, while studying, I came across this practice project which is to write a program to run the collatz sequence from any number until it reaches 1, the code works but it prints each output twice.

```
`def collatz():
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2
    else:
        print(number * 3 + 1)
        return number * 3 + 1
number = 5
print("hi pick a number")
while number != 1:
    try:
        number = int(input())
        while number != 1:
            collatz()
            number = collatz()
    except ValueError:
        print("you should pick a number!")`
```

hi pick a number
16
8
8
4
4
2
2
1
1

> > > 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you call twice **collatz()** so it print twice